# getWidth for a child view within DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

1. I have a DialogFragment class named DF.java which uses a linearlayout based layout named DF.xml.
2. The child elements (again linearlayouts) in DF.xml have their widths set to 0dp and are calculated using weights.
3. I plan to show the DialogFragment DF from an activity on a button click, which works fine and the DialogFragment loads fine.

Now, when the DialogFragment DF shows up, I need to get the width of one of its child elements (a linearlayout).

I have tried getWidth, getMeaseuredWidth, ViewTreeObserver etc in onCreateDialog but result is always zero.

Code to show DialogFragment

```
    DF dialog = DF.newInstance(context, "DFInstance");
    dialog.show(((Activity)context).getFragmentManager(), "DFInstance");
```

Code within DialogFragment DF.java class

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_DF,
            null);
    CurrentDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.DFTheme);
    CurrentDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    CurrentDialog.setContentView(dialog_layout);
    CurrentDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    CurrentDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            //Tried getting width here using many approaches, Ex:
            int Width1 = (((Dialog)dialog).findViewById(R.Id.fieldForWidth)).getWidth();
            // Also tried using MeasureSpec here and then getMeasuresWidth
            // Also tried adding above code in ViewTreeObserver here.
        }

    });
    Window window = CurrentDialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    CurrentDialog.show();

    return CurrentDialog;
}
```

But strangely, if I choose against DialogFragment, and I show the Dialog directly from my main activity, then same code returns width value perfectly within onShow, using getWidth().

But I really need to do this via DialogFragment for the sake of code organization.

Any assistance or pointers as to what I am doing wrong here will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To get the width of the child `LinearLayout` in the `DialogFragment`, you can use an `OnShowListener` together with `getMeasuredWidth()`:

```
final int width;

myDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            width = ((Dialog)dialog).findViewById(R.id.field_for_width).getMeasuredWidth());

        }
    });
```

This works for a child `View` (just a plain `View` as well as a `LinearLayout`) with width set to `match_parent` or `wrap_content`.

Please note that in my test I did not call `CurrentDialog.show()` in `onCreateDialog()` but only used the following lines in the `Activity` code to show the dialog:

```
DialogFragment mDialog = DF.newInstance("x", "yz");
mDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "myCurrentDialog");
```

Comment: Have tried this already.  I have even tried this within an "onclick listener" setup on that child view (fieldForWidth). If I add some text within that childView using a TextView, then I get some width but that's only as much as the width of the text.

So what I am figuring out is that when this dialog is created from within a DialogFragment, the widths are not measured.

Any further suggestions please?

Comment: @StackCoder - maybe the problem is caused by calling "show()" too early? Please take a look at my edited answer - this time, I tested my suggestion before posting and it worked at least in the Android Studio emulator (AppCompatActivity, Lollipop)